# Simple Shell/Bash Program Syntax

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f numbers ]; then echo 0 > numbers; fi
count = 0
while [[$count != 100]]; do
count = `expr $count + 1`
done
```

When I run it in terminal on my Mac, I get the following output:

```
seq_file_gen.sh: line 3: count: command not found
seq_file_gen.sh: line 4: [[: command not found
```

Why am I getting these errors? This script was given to me by my teacher so I have no idea why I can't get this script to run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the correct way to write this script (with spaces)

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ ! -f numbers ]; then echo 0 > numbers; fi
 count=0
 while [[ $count != 100 ]]; do
 count=`expr $count + 1`
 done
```

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote? It seems impossible to ask a basic question without getting down voted.

Comment: Do *not* use spaces around the equals: write `count=0` and `count=\`expr $count + 1\``. I didn't apply the downvote, but I suppose it may be because these are basic shell syntax issues that are determined from reading documentation.

Comment: also you still don't have space in `100]]` and what's with the 'numbers' on line 2? Is this even a complete script?

Comment: I forgot to change it. It worked after I put the space back in. Thanks for the help. Will accept as best answer when I am able to.

Comment: Please show your new, updated script by *adding* it to your question so it's clear what you now have.

Comment: You can always run your programs with shellcheck.net to get some fast checking with good explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spaces before/after `[[` and `]]` like so:

```
while [[ $count != 100 ]]; do
```